# Where to store Column Master Key certificate on ColdFusion server for use with SQL Server Always Encrypted Database Columns

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, coldfusion, certificate, always-encrypted

I'm setting up a new ColdFusion server for use with a SQL Server 2017 database that uses 'Always Encrypted' columns. I'm getting an error when trying to run a SELECT statement from the ColdFusion server.

I've set up and exported the Column Master Key Certificate from SQL Server. I imported it into the ColdFusion server under the ColdFusion Service (Application Server), as well as the Local Machine under Personal (same as SQL Server Management Studio instance). I installed the SQL Server JDBC connector on the ColdFusion server and set up the datasource in the ColdFusion administrator.

The JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://SQLSERVERHOST;databaseName=myDatabase;columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled;
```

The SQL Select Statement:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myTable
```

I expect the SELECT statement to return the decrypted results, but instead get the following error message:

> Error Executing Database Query.
>
> Certificate with thumbprint null not found in certificate store null in certificate location null. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store.

Comment: [This](https://community.hostek.com/t/sql-server-always-encrypted-columns/315#heading--ColdFusion) might be helpful.

Comment: @ssjoel3k - Sounds like it might be an issue with either the CF user account and/or permissions

Comment: Thank you @Ageax, I'll take a look at the CF user account and permissions to see if I find anything.

Comment: Thank you @RRK, that's actually the exact page I've been referencing for setting it up with ColdFusion. I'll go through it again to see if I overlooked anything.